# How to producing soft transitions with custom color ramp?

Tags: node-editor

I’m trying to produce my own color ramp node and went all the way, but my node isn’t capable of having soft transition between colors, any ideas of how to implement that? It also can’t do alpha, but that’s not so much my concern.

I think applying a standard color ramp is necessary, but I don't know the tricks.
[image]

Comment: Hi Guilherme, could you provide a screenshot of you nodes please? Also, what do you mean "went all the way" ?

Comment: oh sorry! I totally forgot!

Comment: What's the purpose of using this group instead of the standard Color Ramp node?

Comment: color and values input, that can respectively be associated with textures and compose a group input.